# How can I check if element matches :host CSS selector?

Tags: javascript, html, css, shadow-dom, custom-element

The element.matches function checks if an element matches a given CSS selector. This can also be used to test elements, even if they are inside a shadow root.

However, the function fails on the `:host` selector, which I feel is expected--at least they way I tried. Take a look at this example:

```js
// Register custom element and shadow root

class CustomElement extends HTMLElement{

  constructor(){
  
    super();
    const shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
    shadowRoot.innerHTML = '<div class="test">Hello, world!</div>';
    
  }
  
}

customElements.define('my-element', CustomElement);

// Question begins here

var shadowRoot = document.querySelector('my-element').shadowRoot;

console.log(shadowRoot.querySelector('.test').matches('.test')); // Works fine
console.log(document.querySelector('my-element').matches(':host')); // Does not work
```

```html
<my-element></my-element>
```

I need a way to call the "matches" as if it were executed from within the shadow root, to return a correct (true) result for the host element of the shadow root.

If any one knows of a way of how I can modify the code to make this work or has any experience with a similar problem and could let me know it would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: This is for custom CSS editor that lets you pick elements based on a CSS selector within the custom element. I simplified it as much as possible, basically I need to check which CSS selector will match which element within the component, including `:host` or any variations thereof, e.g. `:host div`. So the `matches` function should act exactly like CSS selectors would in a stylesheet or inline style within the component.

Comment: What are you doing that makes you think you need to test for this? You shouldn't need to access any element's shadowroot outside of the element itself, so what would this be useful for?

Comment: I fail to understand what you are after also. ``.getRootNode().host`` gets you the _host element of the shadowRoot_

Comment: I am working on a CSS editor that lets you pick elements based on a CSS selector within a web component (the custom element). I simplified it as much as possible in my question, but basically I need to check which CSS selector will match which element within the component, including `:host` or any variations thereof, e.g. `:host div`, etc.

Comment: From DOM Element X you want to know which CSS selectors are applied? I think that can only be done (visually) with the F12 Inspector

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman I am trying to replicate exactly that behavior. It might not be possible as you pointed out, but I figured someone may know of a trick or a workaround.

Comment: If they know, they didn't tell ChatGPT  So your question has nothing to do with ``:host`` or shadowDOM per se.